# Rails show content specific to user group, adding user groups

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm currently new to Rails and I'm making a Rails site that allows users to create a project, and inside the project, users can make lists, submit files, etc.  I am using devise for my user authentication service, and I was looking for the most efficient way to structure this application.

I would like users & projects to be generated when they sign up.  Content will show to its specific project.  I would also like the ability to add additional users to a project.

I was looking at the `current_user` in devise but I'm not sure how to implement into this structure.

Comment: What do you mean that users and projects are generated when they sign up?

Comment: I would like the sign-up process to add a user to the user database, and associate a project into a project database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Devise will handle user creation, update etc. with its own controllers, so you just need to use the correct routes (type `rake routes` to get a list).

If I understand correctly, you want a project to be automatically created when the user is created. You can use an `after_create` callback in the `User` model (other callbacks could also work). I am assuming your `User` model has a `has_many` association with projects:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticable, :registerable # ...etc...

  has_many :projects

  after_create do |user|
    user.projects.create(...)
  end
end
```

If you want a project to have many users, and a user to have many projects, you will instead need a `has_many :through` or a `has_and_belongs_to_many` association between the models. The former uses an additional model to join both, and allows you to store information in the association, and the latter doesn't need an extra model but you do need to create a join table.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I'm assuming I will need to have some sort of reference on everything beneath the project hierarchy that deems what project it is for?  And I would need a similar reference as to which user each project is in reference to?

Comment: Exactly, you need to use associations so establish the relationship between your models. For example, if a user has many projects, you would write `has_many :projects` in your `User` model, `belongs_to :user` in your `Project` model, and define a `user_id` field (an integer) in your projects table in your database. Here's a good guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html